# Why does getPrototypeOf 'null' give an error?

Tags: javascript, object, null, instanceof

So I know 'null' is a type of 'object'

However, when I do Object.getProtoTypeOf(null) I get an error. Same goes for instanceof, which is kinda the same thing.

If null is a type of Object...it should be in it's prototype chain, right?

```
// 'object'
typeof null;  

// gives error - Cannot convert undefined or null to object
Object.getPrototypeOf(null);

// false ---- why?
null instanceof Object
```

Is there something I'm missing, or JS is just too hippie ?!

Comment: `null instanceof 'object'` right hand side of operator is not an object. It should be `null instanceof Object`.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia checkout the first line which gives 'object'. As for instanceof Object, gives false, which is weird.

Comment: `typeof` return string indicating the type. [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). Whereas `instanceof` takes constructor as the right operand and for the objects it happens to be the consturctor function `Object` not `'object'`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia you're correct about the string...fixed the question.

Answer (score 4):

See, `null` is not an object. It's true that `typeof null` evaluates to `'object'`, but it actually came from a limitation and may be considered a quirk - a bug to some extent - of JavaScript. Quoting [this article](http://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html):

> The "`typeof null`" bug is a remnant from the first version of
>   JavaScript. In this version, values were stored in 32 bit units, which
>   consisted of a small type tag (1–3 bits) and the actual data of the
>   value. The type tags were stored in the lower bits of the units. There
>   were five of them:
>
> - 000: `object`. The data is a reference to an object.
> - 1: `int`. The data is a 31 bit signed integer.
> - 010: `double`. The data is a reference to a double floating point number.
> - 100: `string`. The data is a reference to a string.
> - 110: `boolean`. The data is a boolean.
>
> That is, the lowest bit was either one, then the type tag was only one bit long. Or it was zero, then the type tag was three bits in length, providing two
>   additional bits, for four types. Two values were special:
>
> - `undefined` (JSVAL_VOID) was the integer −2<sup>30</sup> (a number outside the integer range).
> - `null` (JSVAL_NULL) was the machine code NULL pointer. Or: an object type tag plus a reference that is zero.
>
> It should now be obvious why typeof thought that null was an object: it examined its type tag and the type tag said “object”.

Now, for the rest operations `null` is treated as a primitive value. That's why, for example, `null instanceof Object` returns false - any primitive will, as it cannot be an instance. Compare `42 instanceof Number` (false) with `typeof 42 === 'number'`.

---

For `Object.getPrototypeOf(null)`, it's a bit different. In [ES5 standard](https://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.2) this function should throw an exception if its argument is a primitive - any primitive:

> When the `getPrototypeOf` function is called with argument `O`, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> - If `Type(O)` is not `Object` throw a `TypeError` exception.
> - Return the value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of `O`.

However, in ES2015 they [changed it](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getprototypeof):

> When the `getPrototypeOf` function is called with argument `O`, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> - Let `obj` be `ToObject(O)`.
> - `ReturnIfAbrupt(obj)`.
> - Return `obj.[[GetPrototypeOf]]()`.

... so `Object.getPrototypeOf(42)` now works. Yet both `Object.getPrototypeOf(undefined)` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(null)` throw the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

This exception is thrown by `ToObject()` method ([doc](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject)) - and it makes sense, as one cannot 'box' `null` and `undefined`. In some ways it's similar to the error you get when trying to access a property of `null` or `undefined`.